# "Broken" links inside a <template> tag

Tags: html, tags, semantic-markup, html5-template

I've recently started using the `<template>` tag for HTML that I process afterwards using a template library, e.g.

```
<template id="tmpl">
  <div class="something">
    <a href="/pages/{{link}}">{{title}}</a>
  </div>
</template>
...
<script>
var output = Mustache.render($('#tmpl').html(), {
  link: 'abc',
  title: 'abc'
});
</script>
```

However, I've come to realise this means I have a broken link (*example.com/pages/{{link}}*) in my HTML. This is a concern, as various crawlers might consider it invalid (in fact, the Google Search Console reports my homepage as having a broken link).

1. Is it valid to use `<template>` this way?
2. Is it better to put it in something like `<script type="text/template">` instead (as seen on the [handlebars.js website](http://handlebarsjs.com/))?

Answer (score 1):

The *output* variable does contain the HTML we would expect, i.e., the rendered template; however, your code does not write the contents of the *output* variable anywhere.

Here is a working example:

```
<template id="tmpl">
  <div class="something">
    <a href="/pages/{{link}}">{{title}}</a>
  </div>
</template>

<span id="output"></span>

<script>
var output = Mustache.render($('#tmpl').html(), {
  link: 'abc',
  title: 'abc'
});
$('#output').html(output);
</script>
```

Google has not properly crawled the test site I setup for this. However, when I asked GoogleBot to render my version of your code it displayed the link inside the `template` element, i.e., `*{{title}}*` and the rendered template link, i.e., `*abc*`. Even though Google says you have a broken link in the `template` element, you really don't when a user views it.

One possible way to get Google to quit indicating that you have a broken link is to surround your `template` tags with `<!--googleoff: anchor--> ...templates... <!--googleon: anchor-->`. These tags stop googlebot from indexing anchor tags contained within.

Example:

```
<!--googleoff: anchor-->
<template id="tmpl">
    <div class="something">
        <a href="/pages/{{link}}">{{title}}</a>
    </div>
</template>
<!--googleon: anchor-->
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually had no idea about the `googleoff` comments! That said, I'm aware my example was not actually rendering anything (I was just using it to show how I'm using the `<template>` tag); my original question (still active) is really about whether this use of `<template>` is semantically (and otherwise) valid or should it be avoided?